# How can I obtain a dataframe from a matrix (2D-array)?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I'd like to transform my array into a dataframe, with the column "Cluster" where there will be the numbers 5,4,2,1, ... and "Trend" with numbers 1,2,3,4,...

```
           [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] 
  cluster    5    4    2    1    2    4    1    2    2     5     1
```

What I expect :

```
               Trend               Cluster
               1                   5
               2                   4
               3                   2
               4                   1
               ...
```

Comment: can you share a reproducible code to create the df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.frame`:

```r
data.frame(Trend = seq_along(mat), t(mat))

#   Trend cluster
# 1     1       5
# 2     2       4
# 3     3       2
```

Reproducible data:

```r
mat <- t(c(5, 4, 2))
rownames(mat) <- "cluster"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cluster <- c(5,4,2,1,2,4,1,2,2,5,1);
data.frame('trend' = seq_len(length(cluster)), cluster)
```

An example: [data.frame example](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/1vBcRem3slg)